# CSS Transition is not working for the first time

Tags: css

I got some functions to change the width of the div `.container` when someone clicks the corresponding button.

The width will be changed immediately without the CSS `transition: 0.9s;` (I highlighted it in the code). The transition will only work after the first time and I don't know why...

Please run the code below then you will understand what I mean:

```js
const settings = {
  Desktop: {
    width: "100%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(2,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  },
  Tablet: {
    width: "60%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(1,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  },
  Phone: {
    width: "30%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(1,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  }
}

function resize(which) {
  let x = document.querySelectorAll(".Container");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.width = settings[which].width;
  }
  x = document.querySelectorAll(".Setting");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.gridTemplateColumns = settings[which].gridTemplateColumns;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.hr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.Medium {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.Container {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Here is the transition */
  transition: 0.9s;
}

.Setting {
  align-items: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  display: grid;
  text-align: left;
}

.Content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr">
  <button class="Desktop" onclick="resize('Desktop')">Desktop</button>
  <button class="Medium" onclick="resize('Tablet')">Tablet</button>
  <button class="Full" onclick="resize('Phone')">Phone</button>
</div>
<div class="Container">
  <p>This is Heading</p>
  <p>Some text will appear here</p>
  <div class="Setting">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="Content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the initial width for the transition to begin from you'll get the effect you're after. When the transition runs through the start to finish values if there's not an explicit first property the transition won't run. See changes to the `.container` class below.

```js
const settings = {
  Desktop: {
    width: "100%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(2,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  },
  Tablet: {
    width: "60%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(1,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  },
  Phone: {
    width: "30%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(1,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  }
}

function resize(which) {
  let x = document.querySelectorAll(".Container");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.width = settings[which].width;
  }
  x = document.querySelectorAll(".Setting");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.gridTemplateColumns = settings[which].gridTemplateColumns;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.hr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.Medium {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.Container {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 430px;
  transition: width 0.9s;
  will-change: width;
}

.Setting {
  align-items: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  display: grid;
  text-align: left;
}

.Content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr">
  <button class="Desktop" onclick="resize('Desktop')">Desktop</button>
  <button class="Medium" onclick="resize('Tablet')">Tablet</button>
  <button class="Full" onclick="resize('Phone')">Phone</button>
</div>
<div class="Container">
  <p>This is Heading</p>
  <p>Some text will appear here</p>
  <div class="Setting">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="Content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```